# How to append \n literally with StringBuffer?

Tags: java

How to append "\n", literally, not like special character.

I wont to achive this:

```
StringBuffer st = new StringBuffer;

st.append(text1);
st.append("\n");
st.append(text2);
```

and the output string to be:

```
text1 \n text2
```

not

```
text1
text2
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
StringBuffer st = new StringBuffer();
st.append("Hello");
st.append("\\n"); //<- the first \ escapes the second
st.append("World");
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the backslash if you want to print a literal backslash:

```
st.append("\\n");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
st.append("\\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

Escape "\" with another \:

```
st.append(" \\n ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape escaping symbol `\`. It means that you have to append `"\\n"`

Answer (score 1):

Check to use StringBuilder for better performance if no synchronization is needed and escape the special character (as mentioned in other answers before).